# Android onActivityResult shutdown (kinetic)

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, shutdown, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

How should I properly use onActivityResult in my MainActivity that extends RosActivity?

In my MainActivity, I call another activity using startactivityforresult, then in that activity I call

Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
resultIntent.putExtra(INSERTED_ORDER, orderET.getText().toString());
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
finish();

but after that the method shutdown() of RosActivity is getting called closing the application.

Without RosActivity my code works correctly and the only difference is that I added
super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
otherwise init(NodeMainExecutor nodeMainExecutor) is not getting called after MasterChooser activity.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/303603/android-onactivityresult-shutdown-(kinetic)/) by [eminemm](https://answers.ros.org/users/37564/eminemm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2018-09-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just found where the problem is. Basically when I call super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data) inside onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data), in my RosActivity, it calls onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data) of RosActivity.java where if (requestCode != MASTER_CHOOSER_REQUEST_CODE) it calls nodeMainExecutorService.forceShutdown();

In my MainActivity, inside onActivityResult I call super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data) only when requestCode is different from the one I created resolving the problem.

---

Originally posted by [eminemm](https://answers.ros.org/users/37564/eminemm/) with karma: 16 on 2018-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0